# Definition of an extension field question

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, definition, extension-field

My question concerns Kronecker's theorem and Extension fields.

Kronecker's Theorem:

> Let $F$ be a field and let $f (x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$.
>   Then there is an extension field $E$ of $F$ in which $f(x)$ has a zero.

The proof of Kronecker's theorem is given as follows:

Since $F[x]$ is a unique factorization domain, $f (x)$ has an irreducible
factor, say, $p(x)$. Clearly, it suffices to construct an extension
field $E$ of $F$ in which $p(x)$ has a zero. **Our candidate for $E$ is $F[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$.**  Due to a previous theorem, this is a field.  Also, since the mapping of $\phi: F \rightarrow E$ given by $\phi(a) = a + \langle p(x) \rangle$ is
one-to-one and preserves both operations, $E$ has a subfield isomorphic to $F$. We may think of $E$ as containing $F$ if we simply identify the coset
$a + \langle p(x) \rangle$ with its unique coset representative a that belongs to $F$.

Then to show $p(x)$ has a zero in $E$, we substitute in $x + \langle p(x) \rangle$ into $p(x)$ and get $p(x) + \langle p(x) \rangle$ = $0 + \langle p(x) \rangle$.

**My question is:**  This does not show that $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ is an extension field of $F$, only that there's a homomorphic image of $F$ that's a subfield of $E$.  Because by the definition of an extension field:

> A field $E$ is an extension field of a field $F$ if $F \subseteq E$ and the operations of $F$ are those of $E$ restricted to $F$.

But $F$ is not a subset of $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ because elements of $F$ are just the elements while elements of $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ are of the form $g(x) + \langle p(x) \rangle$, which are cosets.  Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here?

Comment: The $g(x)$ which are constants, i.e. no $x$ terms are the $F$ inside of them.

Comment: @AdamHughes What do you mean?  $g(x)$ is an element from $F[x]$ so it can be non-constants.

Comment: Yes, but you asked how $F\subseteq E$, it is embedded via the constants. But the embedding is just an injection, it's not saying *everything* is a constant.

Comment: @AdamHughes But elements of $F$ are just elements while elements of $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle $ are cosets of the form $g(x) + \langle p(x) \rangle$, so how could $F \subseteq E$ when no $c \in F = c \in F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$?

Comment: that's fair, technically $c$ here is represented by $c+(p(x))$. It's common to consider the cosets just by their representatives, however, and this is likely the intent even if the language is a bit abused.

Comment: @AdamHughes What do you mean by consider the cosets just by their representatives?  and what would be a better way to say it if the language seems abusive?

Comment: I would say $F$ is canonically embedded in $E$, which is usually what one means when they say $F\subseteq E$ in this context. It means there is an obvious way to put $F$ into $E$, in this case $c\mapsto c + (p(x))$ is the embedding.

Comment: @AdamHughes What does the phrase canonically embedded mean?

Comment: I said in the last post "it means there is an obvious way..."

Comment: @AdamHughes So then, following the wording specifically, Kroneckers theorem is wrong because it's not showing a specific subset relationship that is explicitly defined in the definition for extension fields?  If it was changed to say there's an extension field $E$ for a homomorphic image of $F$ that is a subfield of $E$ would that be more correct?

Comment: Yes, basically. But for all intents and purposes the distinction is known to be highly superficial. This is also why we often say things which are isomorphic are "the same thing," even if that's not technically equality.

Answer (score 1):

We have a canonical injective morphism of fields
$$F\longrightarrow F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$$
given by $f\mapsto f+\langle p(x)\rangle$. This exhibits $F$ as a subfield of $F(x)/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Comment: But what element of $F$ is an element of $F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$?

Comment: Pedantically speaking the restriction of the projection displays $F$ as isomorphic to but not equal to a subfield of $F[x]/(p(x))$ and that's the OP"s concern.